# Time dilation on Satellites due to GR

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, satellites

I am trying to determine the time dilation onboard a satellite (say GPS @ 20,000km) w.r.t an observer on the earth. I have already determined the special relativity component using:

$$
t' = \frac{t}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}
$$

And I got the correct answer for the time dilation simply due to relative motion (7 microseconds after 24 hrs). Im not sure if determining the component due to GR is this simple, but my first attempt was to evaluate it using the equation to determiine gravitational time dilation outside a non rotating sphere in a circular orbit using the Schwarzschild metric.

$$
t' = t\sqrt{1-\frac{3GM}{rc^2}}
$$

I dont seem to be getting the correct answer (45 microseconds after 24 hrs). Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equation you quote:

$$ t' = t\sqrt{1-\frac{3GM}{rc^2}} \tag{1} $$

gives the time relative to an observer at infinity. You want the time relative to an observer on the Earth's surface. You need to calculate:

$$ t_\text{satellite} = t\sqrt{1-\frac{3GM}{r_\text{satellite}c^2}} $$

and:

$$ t_\text{Earth} = t\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{r_\text{Earth}c^2}} $$

where $r_\text{Earth}$ is the radius of the Earth and $r_\text{satellite}$ is the radius of the satellite's orbit (measured from the centre of the Earth). The relative time dilation is then the ratio of these two times.

Note that equation (1) combines the special and general relativity contributions to the time dilation i.e. it includes both the gravitational time dilation and the effect of the orbital velocity. The observer on the Earth's surface isn't in a circular orbit so the equation is slightly different (a factor of 2 in the square root rather than 3).

Incidentally, when the gravitational field is weak (like the Earth's) we can use the weak field approximation for time dilation:

$$ \frac{dt_B}{dt_A} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{2(\Phi_A - \Phi_B)}{c^2}} \tag{1} $$

The quantity $\Phi_A - \Phi_B$ is the difference in the Newtonian gravitational potential energy between $A$ and $B$, and $dt_B/dt_A$ is the time dilation of $B$'s clock relative to $A$'s clock.

Comment: The observer on earth is in a couple of different orbits - once around the Sun, and once every 24 hours around the center of Earth. The former orbit is "shared" by the satellite, while the latter is "very slow". Is it worth computing the correction needed for the latter (which is dependent on latitude)?

Comment: @Floris: no :-)

Comment: See also [Sagnac distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_analysis_for_the_Global_Positioning_System#Sagnac_distortion). It results in an error "on the order of hundreds of nanoseconds, or tens of meters in position".

Comment: @Floris No (well, of course it depends on your application): look at John's equation (1): if the Newtonian approximation is mildly affected by an effect, then the error in a Newtonian potential difference becomes that error divided by $c^2$ in the weak field time dilation factor.

Comment: @Floris: If someone wants to post this as a question I'd be happy to give a detailed answer. It's pretty straightforward as you just integrate the metric for constant $r$ and $\theta$ and $\phi = \omega tr\sin\theta$. But I think the calculation is unnecessary here.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. Does equation 4 incroporate special relativity aswell? IT seems like its derived from 1

Comment: @Kafros: if you really want to include the effect of the Earth's rotation as Floris suggests then answer a new question and I'll be happy to explain. I'm not sure it's worth it though.

Comment: Ok so I worked it out with constant values up to 2 s.f and I am getting a dilation of 58 microseconds over one day. If equation 4 incorporates special relativity that's an error of 20 microseconds, if not its an error of 27 microseconds.Either way, will I not get the correct result (up to 2 s.f) without incorporating the Earth's rotation?

Comment: Correction: the error is 13 microseconds if its not accounting for relativity. Also you mentioned it's an approximation, should the approximation yield 20% error?

Comment: @Kafros: I've just done the calculation to check and I get 38us per day, which is exactly right. For the Earth I get t'/t = 0.999999999305 and for the satellite I get t'/t = 0.999999999975. The ratio of these two is 1.000000000445. Subtract 1 off this and multiply by the 86400 seconds in a  day and the answer is 38us.

Comment: @JohnRennie, I'm curious, could you use some form of $\sqrt{1-\frac{3GM}{rc^2}}$ to calculate the precession of Mercury's parhelion? If so, it would seem it would only work for a circular orbit and not one with an eccentricity of 0.2056 as Mercury's orbit is. As such, If I'm even barking up the right tree, what would a correct formulation be, accounting for Mercury's eccentric orbit?